# Restore GCE VM after trial period ends

Tags: virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, restore, trial

Unfortunately we forgot to upgrade our GCE trial version, so Google deleted our project. Is there any chances to restore data?
How could we manage this problem? We would like to use the service, only forgot to upgrade :(

### Thanks for your help,

Szabolcs Mohácsi

Answer (score 0):

For future searchers, this was answered on the gce-discussion Google Group. Data and resources remain in the system for 30 days after trial expiration, and if you upgrade to a paid account you will be able to access them again. (source: [free trial FAQ](https://cloud.google.com/free-trial/#faq)).